# how to access a type defined in one .ml file in another .ml file

Tags: ocaml

In a.ml a record type t is defined and is also defined transparently
in a.mli, i.e. in d interface so that the type definition is available
to all other files.

a.ml also has a function, func, which returns a list of t.

Now in another file, b.ml  i m calling func, now obviously ocaml
compiler wud nt be able to infer d type of objects stored in d list,
for compiler its just a list. so in b.ml, i hav something like dis,

```
let tlist = A.func in
let vart = List.hd tlist in
printf "%s\n" vart.name     (*name is a field in record t*)
```

Now here i get a compiler error sayin "Unbound record field label
name" which makes sense as compiler can't infer d type of vart.

my first question: how do I explicitly provide d type of vart as t
here?
                         i tried doing "let vart:A.t =  " but got the
same error.

I also tried creating another function to fetch the first element of d
list and mentioning return type as A.t, but then i got the "Unbound
value A.t". I did this:

```
let firstt = function
     [] -> 0
   | x :: _ -> A.t x ;;
```

The problem is compiler is unable to recognize A.t (a type) in b.ml
but is able to recognize function A.func. If I remove A.t from the
b.ml, i don'get any compiler errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler **is** able to recognize `A.t` to designate type `t` from file `a.ml`.

On the other hand, `t x` where `t` is a type and `x` a variable is not a valid expression. This is the source of your problem. The compiler looks for the name `t` in the variables exported by `a.ml`. Since it cannot find this name used for a variable, it reports an error.

Now for what you were trying to do:

- type annotations are not hints to the compiler in OCaml. It has an algorithm to infer the (most general, with some exceptions I am not entering into) type and then it checks that your annotation is at least a particularization of the most general type. The type annotation you provide will never (again, with some possible exceptions that do not concern you) make it change its mind.
- To access in file `b.ml` the field `f` of a record `r` of type `A.t`, type `r.A.f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let tlist = A.func in
let vart = List.hd tlist in
printf "%s\n" vart.name     (*name is a field in record t*)
```

Here `tlist` is a function, I suppose it is of type `'a -> A.t list`, but you are applying an `List.hd` on that function when you write `let vart = List.hd tlist`.

You should provide the argument for your function to get the list of `A.t` for example `let tlist = A.func (your_argument-s-_here)`, I guess this is the source of your error, the compiler is able to infer types between modules.